# firebase authorization in a laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, firebase-authentication

I use firebase authentication in my laravel project and I am curious if there is such a way to give users roles/permissions.

Normally I use laravel authorization to get over it but now my user data are on the firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication (as its name implies) only handles authentication: verifying the user's identity. It intentionally does not provide any form of authorization: determining what the user's access permissions are.

Many of Firebase's other products have their own authorization mechanism that builds on top of Authentication, such as the server-side [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) of the Realtime Database, Cloud Firestore, and Cloud Storage.

You will need to do something similar in your own server-side code to implement authorization for your app. You'll typically follow this recipe:

1. Pass the ID token of the user from the client to your server-side code.
2. Decode and [verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) to securely determine who the user is.
3. Look up the authorization of the user, either in a data store of your own, and/or from the [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) from their token.
4. Enforce that the user only accesses the data they're authorized for.

This is pretty much the same process that Firebase's own services also follow.